# Publish Arcgis Server with another local machine/computer

Tags: postgis, arcgis-server, installation

I use ArcGIS server and desktop to develop web-based GIS in the city of Balikpapan, Indonesia. I found the error when using a PostgreSQL database registers. Domain server that I use is http://simtaru.bappeda.balikpapan.go.id. when I publish a service from another computer, why the error? is there any advice and input?

[image]

Comment: Please always include error messages *as ASCII text in the body of questions*. This allows the question to be searched.  You should also include the connection parameters (excepting password) used to register the database (127.0.0.1 [aka 'localhost'] would not be valid on any host other than the database server).